# Django-hosts not serving custom urlconf

Tags: python, django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to use django-hosts to serve some plain text data at api.mysite.com.  My project is using the nginx, gunicorn, django, postgres configuration described here:

[digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn)

I have installed django-hosts and followed the documentation here: [django-hosts](http://django-hosts.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) , but when I visit api.mysite.com the DNS lookup fails.  I have made the changes to my settings.py file such as,

```
ROOT_HOSTCONF = 'mysite.hosts'

DEFAULT_HOST = 'www'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
#. . . 
'django_hosts',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
#. . . 
'django_hosts.middleware.HostsMiddleware',
)
```

I have an apiurls.py file next to my urls.py that looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from mysite.views import hello

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', hello),
)
```

this is my normal urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from mysite.views import hello

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^hello/', hello),

)
```

mysite.com/hello works as expected.

and my hosts.py file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django_hosts import patterns, host

host_patterns = patterns('',
        host(r'www', settings.ROOT_URLCONF, name='www'),
        host(r'api', settings.ROOT_URLCONF, name='api'),
)
```

As you can see, I just set the api host to serve the ROOT_URLCONF to see if it was an issue with my custom url config file, but it didn't work.  Any visits to api.mysite.com just get the dns lookup failure no matter what I change.  www.mysite.com works fine as does www.mysite.com/hello.

Any ideas?

EDIT:  Do I need to configure NGINX to pass api.mysite.com somehow?  I tried adding *.mysite.com to server_name iny my NGINX config, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it just took a really long time for my DNS changes to propagate, almost 12 hours, and all is well now.  If anyone finds this, my configuration works just fine and as intended.